# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir todos los valores de un for en varios TextField? Uso java

Tags: bucle-for, javafx, intellij-idea, scenebuilder, textfield

Verán, soy estudiante y estoy haciendo un programa de matemáticas, la cuestión es que, para ello, el usuario introduce un valor de n (5, por ejemplo) y el programa debe mostrar los valores de 0 a n en diferentes TextFields (con un límite de 6), por ejemplo, si el usuario introduce 5 como valor de n, el programa debería mostrar los valores: 0,1,2,3,4,5 en 6 TextFields diferentes

Uso SceneBuilder e IntelliJ, por lo que los TextField los coloco en SceneBuilder directamente
Lo que se me ocurrió fue usar un for:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(txtN.getText());
        for(int x=0;x<=n;x++){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
}
```

Si tienen alguna otra sugerencia que no sea utilizar un for, los leo:(

Comment: Tendrías que crear `n` TextField de manera dinámica para poder imprimir cada valor. Si esto es un ejercicio conviene señalarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Creas un for pero no intentas ni siquiera añadir el TextField en el SceneBuilder, por favor, podrias editar la pregunta y añadir como creas aun que sea uno de estos? Sino parece que estas asignando la tarea a alguien de la comunidad.

Comment: Si no creas los TextFields dinámicamente, deberías meterlos en una estructura (ej. arreglo) para poder recorrerlos y asignar su valor.

Comment: Heey, lamento si la pregunta no fue clara, no pretendía darle la tarea a la comunidad, es solo que es la primer pregunta que hago y la verdad no la formulé correctamente. Fallo mío. Lo terminé resolviendo de manera distinta, porque, como mencionan (acertadamente) los TextFields tendrían que crearse de manera dinámica; mi solución fue usar un TableView donde se fueran agregando filas según lo requiriera el usuario. Nuevamente, me disculpo por no haber añadido la información necesaria.

Comment: Ya sea table o text es importante limpiar los hijos para que los objetos de iteraciones anteriores se vayan a garbage collector en tableview es 'tableview. getItems(). clear()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**añadir nodos con for loop**

[image: numbers]

Sugiero el nodo `Text` en vez de `TextField` como nodo si no no se va a editar. Text es texto plano no editable directamente por el usuario.Esta comentado la misma línea pero crea un nuevo text en vez de textfield .
El programa usa el mismo for loop , pero en [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) . Debe tomar en cuenta que en esta aproximación no revisa si es un int válido o no . Para ello esta [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html).
Toda vez que se cambia un valor se debe limpiar los hijos con `getChildren().clear()`
Esta es una app funcional de javafx en una sola clase que puede revisar .
**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        TextField txtN = new TextField();
        txtN.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            hBox.getChildren().clear();
            int n = Integer.parseInt(txtN.getText());
            for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++) {
                hBox.getChildren().add(new TextField(String.valueOf(x)));
             //   hBox.getChildren().add(new Text(String.valueOf(x)));
            }

        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox(hBox, txtN);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 320, 240);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```